# Running a custom function - settings.func is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a jQuery plugin which I want to call a custom function on like so...

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.testPlugin= function(options) {

        var settings = {
            func: null
        };

        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

        settings.func();
    };

})(jQuery);
```

In this case I want to run the `doSomething` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       

    $('div').testPlugin({
        func: 'doSomething'
    });

});

function doSomething() {
    alert('hello');
}
```

I always get the error `settings.func is not a function` so I am having to use:

```
eval(settings.func+"()");
```

Intead of:

```
settings.func();
```

Which is not ideal! Any ideas why I am getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're assigning a string to `settings.func`, not a function.  Strings are never functions, even if they contain the name of a function.

Functions are first-class citizens, however, which means you can use them as you would any other variable, assigning them to variables or passing them as arguments to other functions.  Change:

```
$('div').testPlugin({
    func: 'doSomething'
});
```

to

```
$('div').testPlugin({
    func: doSomething
});
```

and it should work.

Comment: Just to add onto @Andy- You should also declare the function doSomething before using it in the plugin, so try and move the doSomething declaration before calling your plugin.

Comment: @leonxki: actually, in this case that isn't necessary.  Function declarations are "hoisted", meaning they are parsed and available before any other code executes.  This behaviour differs from function expressions, however, so you might want to search Google to find out the differences between function declarations and function expressions.